# Kubenetes cluster: All pods, disk deployment down

Tags: kubernetes

I used Kubernetes cluster to deploy my server. In this early morning, all pods in my cluster were deleted and restarted, caused i lost all data (store on pv) on pod. I used this guide to create pv disk for my pod https://medium.com/@Sushil_Kumar/readwritemany-persistent-volumes-in-google-kubernetes-engine-a0b93e203180.  I attached a picture that log my situation. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j7ES.png)

Could someone help me figure out what happen to my cluster? Why do all pods on my cluster down? Thanks

Regards

Hoa Nguyen

Comment: Without further infos this is hard. But probably you did not pin the PVC? Causing new PVC created after the POD restarts. No possbility to analyse why that happened without more infos as well.

Comment: You should raise a support case on [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and report Your issue. Most logs are only accessible only to official GCP support.